# Google Spreadsheet SUMIF with criterion containing wildcards

Tags: google-sheets

Please see the data example in the image below...

I would like to sum the amounts separately by months and years.

How can I do this using `SUMIF` ?

My idea was very simple - to have formula for each month and for each year, like this:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A100,"2018-01-*",B1:B100)
=SUMIF(A1:A100,"2018-02-*",B1:B100)
=SUMIF(A1:A100,"2018-03-*",B1:B100)
..etc
=SUMIF(A1:A100,"2018-*",B1:B100)
=SUMIF(A1:A100,"2019-*",B1:B100)
..etc
```

But this formulas don't work. Something is wrong with the `criterion`.

So what am I doing wrong ? Am I using wildcards incorrectly ?

[Example of data that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2gWi.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that cells containing dates are special and cannot be compared to `criterion` like `2018-08-*`.

The workaround is to use `SUMIFS` and then set each `criterion` with the `DATE()` function. Here is example for `2018-07`:

```
=SUMIFS(B2:B100,A2:A100,">="&DATE(2018,7,1),A2:A100,"<"&DATE(2018,8,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Query as in the image below (showing sum for 8th month - August):

[image]

By changing `month(A)+1=8` you will have different months.
Code:

```
=QUERY(A1:B5;"select sum(B) where month(A)+1=8 label sum(B) ''";0)
```

Is that OK for you?